# Добавление в таблицу PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

Столкнулся с проблемой пишу приложение с базой данных PostgreSQL.
Оно не маленькое поэтому думаю нет смысла описывать все что делает, а конкретно проблема в том что пользователь создает свою таблицу в базе. После добавляет количество столбцов в таблице названия , тип и так далее. И тут у меня делема , когда идет заполение таблицы как правильно это сделать когда я не могу сразу в код написать точное количество столбцов ?
Вот есть код который добавляет фиксированое значение столбов :

```
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO readbook (Language, Type, Author, Name, Page) VALUES (@n1, @q1, @w1, @e1, @r1)", conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("n1", comboBox1.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("q1", comboBox2.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("w1", textBox1.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("e1", textBox2.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("r1", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));

                    int nRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    
                }
```

Тут мне понятно как сделать, а ка сделать что бы в коде не зная сразу точное количество столбцов добавлять данные ?

Например , один пользователь выбрал таблицу с 4 столбцами , а второй выбрал таблицу с 12 столбцами, и она заполняют ее, как универсально написать запрос ?

Я сам новичек и я почемуто уверен что коряво обьяснил проблему , и если будут вопросы задавайте , постараюсь детальней написать !

Comment: Не надо Вам такой универсальности - поверьте на слово...

Comment: Нужно, раз я придумал такое приложение я хочу довести его до конца

Comment: Сохраняйте данные в один столбец в виде json/xml.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую

Comment: Господи, ну зачем учиться делать через задницу-то? почитайте хоть что-нибудь по реляционным базам данных! и особенно обращайте внимание на термин "детерминированность".